# Select data from the list of string sql

Tags: c#, sql

I wanted to select the data from the list of string that already being defined, and later on will filter based on that list with some conditions.

But while I am trying the below code:

```
List<string> inventoryList = new List<string>();

inventoryList.Add("a147");
inventoryList.Add("w150");

string.Format("SELECT * FROM (VALUES '{0}') AS InventoryList(InventoryCode)"
                    + " SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM [InventoryList] a INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[InventoryCode] = b.[PlayerInventoryCode] WHERE b.[PlayerID] = 146", inventoryList);

--- Other codes to connect to the database and so on ----
```

It will generate it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]') AS InventoryList(InventoryCode) SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM [InventoryList] a INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[InventoryCode] = b.[PlayerInventoryCode] WHERE b.[PlayerID] = 146
```

and the error that I am getting is:

> Exception: Incorrect syntax near 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

***EDIT:***

Expected result will create the `InventoryList` table with `InventoryCode` for the column name with the above values inside:

```
InventoryList <-- table
InventoryCode <-- column name
1. a147
2. w150
```

Then, will be query like normal:

```
SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM InventoryList a INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] ....
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Instead how does your query should looks ??

Comment: Hi @ekad and @Mohid Shrivastava, the query should look like this: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES 'a147', 'w150') AS InventoryList(InventoryCode)` then, after the table `InventoryList` with the column name `InventoryCode` have the following data: `a147` and `w150`, then I will query the result with another table. Thanks

Comment: `inventoryList` should be `String.Join("','",inventoryList.ToArray())`

Comment: @Reinhardt try removing the InventoryCode in alias name

Comment: Hi @BalajiMarimuthu, I have tried to remove the `InventoryCode` in alias name, but the error that I get is `Incorrect syntax near 'a147'`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected SQL query below

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 'a147', 'w150') AS InventoryList(InventoryCode)
SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM [InventoryList] a INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[InventoryCode] = b.[PlayerInventoryCode] WHERE b.[PlayerID] = 146
```

has two problems. The first problem is, the following `SELECT` statement is invalid

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 'a147', 'w150') AS InventoryList(InventoryCode)
```

You'll get `Incorrect syntax near 'a147'` error. It should include `(` and `)` as below

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('a147'), ('w150')) AS InventoryList(InventoryCode)
```

The second problem, you can't do `SELECT` from `InventoryList` in the second `SELECT` statement as below

```
SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM [InventoryList] a
```

because `InventoryList` isn't a real table. You'll get `Invalid object name 'InventoryList'` error.

You should combine both statements as below

```
SELECT a.[InventoryCode] 
FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('a147'), ('w150')) AS InventoryList(InventoryCode)) a 
INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] b WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON a.[InventoryCode] = b.[PlayerInventoryCode] 
WHERE b.[PlayerID] = 146
```

Now we get to the part of generating the above query using C#. If you have `inventoryList` defined as below

```
List<string> inventoryList = new List<string>();

inventoryList.Add("a147");
inventoryList.Add("w150");
```

You can use a combination of `string.Join` and Linq select like this

```
string values = string.Join(",", inventoryList.Select(x => "('" + x + "')"));
```

to produce the following output: `('a147'),('w150')`, then use the `values` variable as below to produce the expected SQL query

```
string output = string.Format("SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES {0}) AS InventoryList(InventoryCode)) a INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[InventoryCode] = b.[PlayerInventoryCode] WHERE b.[PlayerID] = 146", values);
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yLKsBv

Comment: Thank you @ekad. Well explanation and it is helpful for me to understand more about it and it was already solved. Thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the string.format method as below.

```
string.Format("SELECT * FROM (VALUES '{0}','{1}') AS InventoryList"
                                + " SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM [InventoryList] a INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[InventoryCode] = b.[PlayerInventoryCode] WHERE b.[PlayerID] = 146", inventoryList[0] ,  inventoryList[1]);
```

You could use **string.join** `string.Join("','", inventoryList.ToArray())` for n number of items

```
string.Format("SELECT * FROM (VALUES '{0}') AS InventoryList"
                                + " SELECT a.[InventoryCode] FROM [InventoryList] a INNER JOIN [PlayerAccount] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[InventoryCode] = b.[PlayerInventoryCode] WHERE b.[PlayerID] = 146", string.Join("','", inventoryList.ToArray()));
```

Comment: that will restrict to just 2 items in the list

Comment: @bansi thanks for notified that. i've updated the code.